# How to select specific <ng-content></ng-content> using ViewChild

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Modal component with two ng-content tags.

The template looks like this:

```
  <ng-content select="[slot='header']"></ng-content>
  <ng-content select="[slot='content']"></ng-content>
```

This allows me to use Angular's content projection from other components like this

```
<custom-modal>
<div class="header" slot="header">
Header goes here
</div>
<div class="content" slot="content">
Content goes here
</div>
</custom-modal>
```

What I need, is a way to use `ViewChild` decorator in the `CustomModal` component to target the `<ng-content select="[slot='content']"></ng-content>`

I have tried by defining a `#variableName` in the `ng-content` tag but probably that's not the best approach.